# is fastest a complex LIKE on a single field or a WHERE using "=" on multiple fields?

Tags: mysql

### General question

In general, question is: *is a complex LIKE on a single field faster than a WHERE using "=" on multiple fields* ?

which is the fastest query having more than 100M of records?

1st option:

```
SELECT * from codes WHERE code LIKE "_A__9_2__"
```

2nd option:

```
SELECT * from codes WHERE char_2 = "A" AND char_5 = "9" and char_7= "2"
```

### Context

We have a sw generating more than 100M of fixed length string (9 chars for precision)
We *must* do tons, really tons, it's the goal of sw, of queries using only 1 to 9 chars

I think the only tradeoff of 2nd way is that, indexing every single fields to optimize lookup speed, It will multiply the data a lot.

But, while I think 2nd way it's better, I've not idea if it's really faster as I suppose

Comment: Question: Is `LIKE "_B__R_7____5__X"` the _only_ check you would be performing, or would you have the need for many different types of searches?

Comment: Are you really asking strangers to guess [which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)? Build a test case for each with dummy data and conduct your own performance tests.

Comment: @Stu I am not asking for  a guess, but tips from your collective experience. Mark to close if question is inappropriate. the cumulative problem of a lot of data and multiple indexes is not something I can test with a bit of data. I should build both solutions with all data to understand long term performance

Comment: @realtebo Please refer to Stu's comment.  This is on you to first test both options.  If you still have some doubts or it is not clear which approach is fastest, then come back and ask a question on that.

Comment: I _might_ expect the single `LIKE` expression to outperform the individual letter checks (the latter which you would implement using substring operations), because the former approach requires just a single walk down the string, while the latter might require multiple separate string operations.  But, you should really avoid these checks if you can, because none of them can really use an index.

Comment: 2nd option with according index presence is of course preferred.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what types of searches you need. Is it always char 2, 5, and 7? You could create a single index over a virtual column that extracts those characters. But that's not possible if the search could be any combination of characters.

Comment: Please describe further the data and the goals; there may be some tricks to apply.

Comment: I thought of another approach -- build a very large inverted index of all the possibilities.  It would be very efficient, but take a lot of disk space.  Let me know if you want to discuss it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `foo = 'x'` with `INDEX(foo)` is fast.
- `LIKE 'x'` is just as fast as `= 'x'` -- *if no wild cards are involved*
- `LIKE 'x%'` involves a *trailing* wildcard, so it works like a "range" (eg `BETWEEN`).  This has medium performance if there is an index on that column.
- `LIKE '_A'` is slow; the index would not be used.
- `x='a' AND y='b'` with `INDEX(x,y)` or `INDEX(y,x)` is just as fast as `foo = 'x'` with its index.
- `MID(x, 2, 1) = 'a'` is not [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) , hence is slow because it cannot use an index.

"indexing every single fields to optimize lookup speed"  -- Indexing each of 8 columns is is practical, but probably not as useful as you hope for.

- `char_2 = "A"` may return 100K rows; then those have to be checked for the other columns.
- Having `INDEX(char_2, char5)` might return only 10K rows, but now you need 36 indexes to handle all combos of 2 columns.  There is a hard limit of 64 indexes.  (And a "practical" limit of under 10.)

More on indexing:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)